# Requests and Feedposts not stretching to fit content

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I am doing standard FB.ui requests and feed posts which have been working more or less flawlessly for about 4 months. Then in the last couple of days I have noticed that they have stopped working properly across all browsers. They do not stretch to fit their vertical content. This includes both the icons that represent a users FB friends and text content in a post. I thought perhaps I had done something to my javascript and so I deleted my main page's html content and replaced it with the 'JavaScript Example' from [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests) page. The results were the same (as pictured below). Is something broken on Facebook's side or did someone change a setting in my app? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with Facebook, not me. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194725433940802?browse=search_4ec6fc906590d7384024850